# How can I install 12.04.2?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I have never installed an OS before.

I upgraded to 13.04 and it has been a total disaster.  I now want to go back to 12.04.2, but will have to install it totally.  I tried following the instructions, but the computer doesn't do anything that instructions tell me to do.

I have downloaded it to a flash drive, but there seems to be no starting point that I can identify.

Where do I start?

Also, is it possible to download it directly from the hard drive, or does it have to be from an external source?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first, if you have user files in your computer, back them up...

1. Download Ubuntu 12.04 LTS .iso file, from here:

   http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
2. Download a Bootable USB creator, any would work...
3. Now, after you downloaded the USB creator, insert a USB, and the .iso file you downloaded, and "install" Ubuntu to your USB.
4. After you done that, reboot your computer with the USB inside.
5. Now, when Ubuntu has booted, select the option to install Ubuntu.
6. Proceed with the installation process and reboot your computer again.

Now you're done with your computer. If you still have trouble, you can count onthe AskUbuntu community!

Answer (score 0):

installing ubuntu is very easy.

there are two easy methods
using CD or USB

Using CD is very recommended way to do..

download ubuntu from ubuntu iso download page choose 12.04 you want

burn iso to your cd using iso burner software. i am using bwgburn "freeware"

reboot your computer and boot from cd
you can follow the next instruction shown on every step..
or you can email/chat me on my gmail account unu.net@gmail.com for more information that i may help

"sorry for my bad english"